# No feed email on changes made by self

Tags: feature-request

I edited the tags on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41373834/1307905) and the new tag [ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruamel.yaml) (and in this case also the incorrect old one), is where I normally get a notification for via email.

My experience is that I only get those emails if I haven't already opened a matching message (e.g. by clicking the message after I see it appear in one of my "filter" tabs).

I was a bit surprised to get an email that there was a new message tagged `ruamel.yaml` a few minutes later. I already had seen that message (and I had even gotten an email about it before) and secondly because **I was the one adding that tag**. I would have assumed that after finishing the tag edit, the system would know I already had seen that change (and not sent an email notification), even if it might not explicitly check if I were the one making the change.

If this wasn't a glitch, can these feed related mails on actions by myself explicitly be suppressed? Some might not 100% agree, but I normally know what I am (cq. have been) doing.